# Magento 2 custom style sheet for my custom theme

Tags: magento2, css, less-css

i created a file called `breakpoint.less` in `pub\static\frontend\vendor\themename\en_US\css\source` and it produces the output as `breakpoint.css` in `pub\static\frontend\vendor\themename\en_US\css\source` is it a correct way to create a custom less file in Magento 2.

can anyone help me and please explain the correct way to override the theme stylesheet

Answer (score 0):

You are doing is not correct way. Don't work on pub folder.

How to create CSS and already lot of ans here.

I will provide some helpful link here.  Hope it will helpful for you.

For Reference :

[How to add new breakpoint in magento 2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/124896/how-to-add-new-breakpoint-in-magento-2?answertab=active#tab-top)

[How to add a custom CSS file in Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/108685/how-to-add-a-custom-css-file-in-magento-2?answertab=active#tab-top)

Comment: if it is useful please accept the ans :)

Answer (score 0):

You should have "Your/Theme" directory in app/design dir

and add default.xml layout for Magento_Theme module with `<head>` section where put the `<css src="your/stylesheet.css">`